SharePoint url access after domain name migration
What happens with user access to a SharePoint url when the domain name is migrated to another Office365 tenant?
Let's say account personX@companyA**.onmicrosoft.com** has access to https://companyA.sharepoint.com/sites/site1. Tomorrow the domain name 'companyA' is migrated to companyB as an extra domain. Will personX still have access to https://companyA.sharepoint.com/sites/site1 or does the default SharePoint url for tenant of companyA become automatically invalid?
My concern is not about authentication (or licenses), but url access.
